# Como eu posso fazer um programa que da resposta de uma formula matematica?

Tags: javascript

gostaria de colocar essa formula no javascript: 
("")/360= "" vai dar um numero com virgula e quero só o primeiro numero antes da virgula ""x360="" agora vai pegar o resultado que deu a multiplicação e vai fazer - o valor inicial ("")

Tem como fazer isso? se vocês poderem me ajudar, desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: Meu amigo eu não entendi foi nada da pergunta! Mas não seria algo assim?
`(1500/360).toFixed(0) - 1500;`.
Em outras palavras: `(x/y).toFixed(0) - y;`

Answer (score 7):

Não sei qual das fórmulas te interessa, mas veja se algo ajuda:

```
 var numero = 1230;

 // se quiser numero/360 = resultado
 var resultado1 = Math.round( numero / 360 ); 

 // se quiser resultado/360 = numero
 var resultado2 = Math.round( numero * 360 );

 // ou se quiser o resto da divisão inteira:
 var resultado3 = numero % 360;
```

Como bem observado pelo @Sergio, pode ser mais adequado usar `Math.floor` no lugar do `Math.round`, se preferir truncar em vez de arredondar.

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/oZmWra)**.

Se não for nada disso, clique em "editar" logo embaixo da sua pergunta e explique com mais detalhes, e preferencialmente exemplos, e deixe um recado aqui na resposta para eu atualizar (mas antes do recado, atualize a pergunta).